Different results for a measured specific rotation when calculated via slope of the plot and by averaging
I have done this Laurent half shade polarimeter experiment, I calculated the average specific rotation $S_r$ by averaging values of $S_r$ corresponding to different angles of deviation for different concentration $c$ and also from the slope of the $\theta$ vs concentration graph. These two values are drastically different. Why is this so?
$$ S_r=\frac{\theta}{\ell c} $$

The slope of the angle:conc graph is $d\theta/dc = S_r\ell$. It isn't clear what averaging you are doing - can you give more details of your calculation?
